# Is there a way to put CSS on hold?

Tags: css, highcharts, css-transforms

I have dashboard, displaying n number of cards. If card contains some charts, but when data is not provided card displays "No data to display". For charts I have been using highchart. Problem is that "No data to display" text is not visible in card. On debug found that, one of highchart CSS have `transform(-50%, -50%);` which causes it to display somewhere in top of screen and its not visible.

I tried overriding existing CSS, but new CSS gets loaded before highchart CSS.

Is there any way, that I load my CSS once highchart CSS are loaded?

Comment: can you not just change the order of the stylesheets so yours is included after the highcharts stylesheet?

Answer (score 1):

You can add a short code in to the head section of the html where you linked your css.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="location of the css file you want to load after loading all the code" media="none" onload="if (media != 'all') {media = 'all'}">
```

**media="none" onload="if (media != 'all') {media = 'all'}"** this code has to be add in your link tag. And it will cause your css to load at the end of loading all the code. Hope it will work for you.